# Calling a variable in SelectLayerByAttribute

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2

I am trying to code a Python add in for ArcGIS 10.2. I have a shape called FACILITIES which contains facilities, a field CATEGORY and I wish to select all the entities that are categorized as "school"
In order to populate a ComboBox into that addin, I use the SelectLayerByAttribute tool, as follows :

```
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("FACILITIES", "NEW_SELECTION","CATEGORY = '" + "school" + "'")
```

It is working properly. But I wish the category to be variable. So I tried like this :

```
SelectedCategory = "school"
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("FACILITIES", "NEW_SELECTION","CATEGORY = '" + SelectedCategory + "'")
```

But even though it seems very similar my Combobox fails to launch.

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using the str.format and three quotes:

```
SelectedCategory = "school"
query = """ CATEGORY = '{0}' """.format(SelectedCategory)
>>> printed: CATEGORY = 'school'
```

A must-read page from Esri help:
[Specifying a query in Python](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//002z0000001r000000)